# What is the difference between these 2 function description ? function func([ b [, c ] ]) and function func([ b ], [ c ])?

Tags: php, function

i was looking at the function reference of php in a book and then i came accross these descriptions of function, i could not understand what is the diff between these two definations ?

```
function some_function([b[,c]])
```

and

```
function some_function([b], [c])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets in syntax descriptions generally mean that the contents are optional. The first function description indicates that you can call the function as:

```
some_function(); // no arguments
some_function(b); // just supply b
some_function(b, c); // supply both b and c
```

This is because the optional argument `c` is inside the brackets that list both arguments.

The second description says that both arguments are optional, but there's no dependency between them. So it can be called as:

```
some_function(); // no arguments
some_function(b); // just supply b
some_function(c); // just supply c
some_function(b, c); // supply both b and c
```

This implies that `b` and `c` have to be different types, so when you call it with a single argument it figures out whether it's `b` or `c` based on its type. The description of the function should explain this.